# SSRS - Expression to calculate percentage based on Tablix data region

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have a SSRS report with the following tablix6:

```
Account Types
----------------------------------------------
Code   Description              Total   %
-----------------------------------------------
A      Status Code: None        46549   
C      Status Code: Close       12956
L      Status Code: Deceased    477
```

The dataset that populates this Tablix filters the data by (Section = 4 and DataType = 4). This in effect, when trying to calculate the sum of Total, I get an incorrect value.

I'm trying to get a sum total of 59982.

I need the sum of total of only this tablix filtered data region in order to calculate the percentage on each line item.

Herewith the end result I'm trying to achieve:

```
Account Types
----------------------------------------------
Code   Description              Total   %
-----------------------------------------------
A      Status Code: None        46549   77%
C      Status Code: Close       12956   21%
L      Status Code: Deceased    477     0.7%
```

Note: this Tablix is filtering a dataset to display selected items only.

Comment: Do you have an SQL statement we can work with?

Answer (score 3):

i would use an expression something along the lines of

```
=sum(Fields!Total.Value) / sum(Fields!Total.Value, "DataSetName")
```

assuming the filter is working as a parameter on the dataset

Answer (score 0):

If you can use the query that was used to generate the first table you have in your question then you can use something like the following to get the percentage:

```
SELECT M.Code, M.Description, M.Total, 
  M.Total / 
  (
    SELECT SUM(S.Total) 
    FROM AcountSummary AS S
  ) * 100 AS PercentageOf
FROM AcountSummary AS M
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the OVER function.

```
SELECT Code, Description, Total, CAST(Total AS FLOAT) / SUM(Total) OVER() [Percentage]
FROM AccountType
```

Add this to your data source,
after this you can format the Textbox to use format P2 for Percentage with 2 decimal places.

Hope this helps